# Using Square to transfer money to my personal checking account

Tags: taxes, income

I'm considering using Square to essentially allow me to use my own credit card to pay my mortgage. If I swipe my own credit card every month will that transaction be counted as income? I'm trying to find a legal way to get my credit card rewards for my mortgage.

Comment: Won't the fee you pay to Square be much more than any rewards you get from your credit card? Also, as noted in an answer below, I think this must violate your terms of use with your CC and/or with Square.

Comment: Tax questions require that you specify your country, since rules vary.

Answer (score 5):

That would not count as income since you would essentially be transferring money "between accounts", though I believe that would also be against your credit card provider and/or Square's Terms of Service.

Edit: As has been mentioned, Square may report this to the IRS as income for you, however more importantly:

**This is 100% against Square's ToS**:

[User Agreement](https://squareup.com/us/en/legal/general/ua) which you are required to accept in creating an account

> Restricted Use
>
> ... You also may not use the Services to process cash advances. You may not use the invoices feature of the Services to send invoices to yourself or in any other manner for which the invoices feature is not intended.

[Commercial Entity Agreement](https://squareup.com/us/en/legal/general/cea) At Visa/Mastercard's discretion, you may be required to agree to this as well `for the acceptance of card payments that are “Commercial Entities” as defined by Visa, Inc. and MasterCard International, Inc. (collectively, the “Card Brands”)` (aka if you use it to accept Visa or MasterCard). Relevant portion:

> Cash Advances.
>
> Seller shall not disburse or advance any cash to a Customer (except as > authorized by the Card Brand Rules) or to itself or any of its representatives, agents, or employees in connection with a Transaction, nor shall Seller accept payment for effecting credits or issuing refunds to a Customer.

This is a form of what is known as [Credit card kiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_card_kiting#Self_payment)

Comment: Although I think the answer is correct that's it's not income, it may be reported as income to the tax authorities by Square since this is not the intended use of Square's service and they won't necessarily know this is what you're doing. (I also agree that it probably violates your terms of service with them, so, if they know this what you are doing, that might create other problems for you.)

Comment: The update with link to "kiting" is very interesting. Not sure that the OP's situation qualifies, but the point about it being potentially criminal may be worth noting for anyone else reading this under different circumstances.

Comment: It doesn't seem like OPs intent since the question even mentions legality, but the actions and results would be the same for their proposed solution. Getting cash advance from a credit card.

Comment: The link to the wikipedia page for so-called "credit card kiting" is almost completely flat out wrong.  The phrase is not an actual legal defined concept, it is virtually unused in the credit card industry.  The wiki page suffers from frequent reverts of edits made by actual subject matter experts, by the original author, who seems to know very little about the consumer credit industry

Comment: @dwoz The Wikipedia page is not authoritative, but once you know the term, you can search and find it places that are. Quick Google search found US court cases and documents on the official FBI website that use the term in a criminal context. There are additional references that appear to address it in a banking / civil context. What's your evidence that this is all wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I don't at all agree that it violates Square terms of service.  But having said that, it's a bloody expensive way to do things.  Square charges beaucoup fees, that more than obliterate any kind of points you might earn.

Only for emergencies, should one do this.

Comment: This is most certainly against Square's Terms of Service. Reference my [updated answer](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/57305/35774)

Comment: The excerpts from the Square Terms of Service provided by @JasonRush seem convincing. Do you have any evidence that contradicts that?